# Sharepoint App-only Access - Permission Review

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, azure-app-registration

I'm sure the question was already asked, but i didn't find any relevant answer...

I have a Sharepoint Online Tenant and i've registered app-only access via "appinx.aspx".
The Access is granted to have a python script accessing Sharepoint.

Registered Apps
i've now seen that i can enumerate the registered Apps with "appprincipals.aspx".
However on one Site it works on the other site there is only other Apps registered - but not the relevant.
Even though i've registered the App on both sites in the same way (at least i hope so)

Is there a way - i.e. via Powershell to retrieve all registered Apps on a site collection?

Permission
I'm pretty sure that i've registered the following permission XML on the App.

However - i'm not sure about it.
Is there a way to review the permission i've set for a dedicated App?

Any ideas are appreciated

Jens

Answer (score 0):

To access data from multiple sites you can register for **app only access** at tenant level **appinx.aspx**.

In case if you have registered the app in 2 different sites and used the same XML but still you are not able to access the other site , it is definitely an issue with the XML format even a little misplacement of arrow wont makes the things.

Try to format the XML and reassign the permission to the app and check.